# How can I get session scoped bean in filter from session? (jsf 2.1)

Tags: spring, session, jsf-2, scope, servlet-filters

How can I retrieve session scoped bean in filter? I have tried like that, but it returns null.

this is my session scoped bean:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="sessionData")
public class SessionData {
    private UserWrapper userWrapper;

public UserWrapper getUserWrapper() {
    return userWrapper;
}

public void setUserWrapper(UserWrapper userWrapper) {
    this.userWrapper = userWrapper;
}

}
```

and this is filter:

```
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);
if(session != null) {
    SessionData sessionData = (SessionData)session.getAttribute("sessionData");
    System.out.println("sessionData:"+sessionData);
}
```

Bu it returns null...

```
sessionData:null;
```

How can I retrieve sessionData bean in filter?

Comment: If the `session` resolves to null it means that the session wasn't even created yet... and cause you are using `getSession(false);` (if you replace false with true a new session will be created... but still that bean wont be present in it and you will have to create it manually and place into session) does it happens all the time ? or only on the first time the filter being called?