# Access session scoped JSF managed bean in web filter

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters, managed-bean, session-scope

I have  SessionScoped bean called userSession to keep track of the user ( username, ifLogged, etc). I want to filter some pages and therefore I need to access the bean from  the webFilter I created. How do I do that? I looks like its even impossible to import the bean to be potenitally visible.

Comment: Related: [How can I get session scoped bean in filter from session? (jsf 2.1)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12748648/1065197)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Under the covers, JSF stores session scoped managed beans as an attribute of the [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) with the managed bean name as key.

So, provided that you've a `@ManagedBean @SessionScoped public class User {}`, just this should do inside the `doFilter()` method:

```
HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession(false);
User user = (session != null) ? (User) session.getAttribute("user") : null;

if (user != null && user.isLoggedIn()) {
    // Logged in.
}
```

Or, if you're actually using CDI instead of JSF to manage beans, then just use `@Inject` directly in the filter.

#### See also:

- [Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name/)
- [Prevent accessing restricted page without login in Jsf2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883430/prevent-accessing-restricted-page-without-login-in-jsf2/)

Comment: What can I tell you @BalusC  you should be awarded as the Master of JSF.

Comment: @BalusC: And how can I check whether the CDI injected (session) bean has been instantiated or not without calling a method on that bean (which would create the bean if it doesn't exist yet)? `session.getAttribute(<userBean>)` doesn't work with CDI. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative you can use CDI-beans and inject your sessionbean normally.