# Getting NoSuchMethodError at a Filter, on calling a function of a Session Scoped Managed Bean

Tags: filter, glassfish, jsf-2.2, managed-bean, nosuchmethoderror

I am developing a Web/EE project, using `GlassFish` `4` as an Application Server.

I have a `SessionScoped` `ManagedBean` called `UserStateBean` and a `AdminDirNotAdminDeniedFilter` that acts as the 2nd filter of the filter chain, and checks if the logged in user per question is an **admin**.

The code of the Filter, in which I get access to the `ManagedBean` is this:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
UserStateBean userState = (UserStateBean) session.getAttribute("userStateBean");
```

And after that I am calling the `isAdmin()` function on the `userState` instance:  `if (!userState.isAdmin())` and that's where I am getting the **NoSuchMethodError**.

*I have verified that the `userState` instance is not null and that contains the correct `username` and `password` using the debugger.*

[This is an extract](http://pastebin.com/Rf0jsLiW) from the `server.log` of `GlassFish`.

And this is the [UserStateBean](http://pastebin.com/2nG5LstS).

Comment: Could we see the bean?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar sure, just added the link!

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar Hmm that's odd, I just restarted GlassFish and it passed that point (I got another error "Unable to create managed bean Property * for managed bean * does not exist", but that's another thing to check). Thanks a lot Jaqen!

Comment: Great :) I'm wondering if JRebel could help with these cases

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is or was wrong with your bean because when I tried to reproduce it the `userStateBean` was always `null`.

But I would suggest that you let CDI manage your bean injection, that's easier and also less coding.

You yust have to change your `@SessionScoped` import of your managed bean from:

```
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
```

to:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
```

Then you can inject your bean into the filter like this:

```
@Inject
private UserStateBean userStateBean;
```

Maybe this can also help you with your new problem :)

**See also:**

- [Access session scoped JSF managed bean in web filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461989/access-session-scoped-jsf-managed-bean-in-web-filter)
- [Why are there different bean management annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057564/why-are-there-different-bean-management-annotations)

Comment: The new problem was I didn't have getters/setters for the Managed Bean property, now it's all good. The thing is that I want to stick to Managed Bean properties, as they don't need a full application server to run (which is what I need for this project's scope). But I'll keep in mind the `CDI`, so thank you for your suggestion!

// Also, the actual solution was weirdly a restart of GlassFish.